# Sending unaccompanied bags from Vietnam to Borneo

Tags: luggage, vietnam, asia, shipping, borneo

We are working in Vietnam in October, and then working in Borneo. We have three weeks between the two jobs and would like to do some back packing during that time. So we would like to send our bags (3 bags of 23kg) ahead - from Hanoi, Vietnam to Sarawak, Borneo. I have looked on line but with little success

Has anyone any advice?

Comment: So you're just trying to find a way to do it, is that it?

Comment: FedEx, UPS, DHL?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious methods are air freight or courier (DHL) or post office.  The first two are quick and reliable but expensive.  The third is economical but not always reliable.  You could also contact a shipping / freight forwarding company in Hanoi to explore options by sea/land.

With air freight or courier, you need to consider the "storage" time, as the bags would travel much quicker than you.  You would need to arrange for the bags to be held until you arrive (not sure how long an airline or courier service would hold your shipment) or have a friend ship the bags closer to your arrival date in Borneo.

You also have customs to consider.  With air freight or sea/land you may need to have a custom broker to deal with customs.  With courier service, they provide customs service as part of the shipping fee.  The Post Office usually also provides custom service.